# Is it possible to use a datetime string in the input html element of type date?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, datetime-format, html-input

I have multiple date elements and I don't want input type 'datetime' and once I get the value from the controller in my Angular app I have a string like this

> "2019-08-09T00:00:0000"

I can't pass this to my input element without it warning me and error'ing out (not displaying the date)

```
<input type="date" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="ceModal.oepDeathDate" (ngModelChange)="markDirty()">
```

I'm looking for a way to use the full datetime string in a date type input,
 so in my .ts file, I don't have to format the string every time (50+) like this

```js
this.claim.deathDate = this.claim.deathDate !== null ?
  this.claim.deathDate.slice(0, 10) :
  null; // "2019-08-09T00:00:0000" => "2019-08-09" accepted by type date
```

Comment: In "*without it warning me*", what is "it"? I.e. what is the thing that is giving you the warning.

Comment: Create a method or function to do it for you?

Comment: the warning is the format warning saying it's not the correct format for date ex. "yyyy-mm-dd" when I'm passing in a "yyyy-mm-ddT00:00:0000". It doesn;t like or accept the time part.